# Slicing a 3D array vs projecting it

Tags: python, image-processing, transformation, projection, scikit-image

[Link to array file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rxsLumcN3kjEDECc-38PXRznmR2p4gCq/view?usp=sharing)

I am new to image processing and trying to understand projection. So when we have a 3D image, it is simply a 3D numpy array and i view it by slicing a 2D array out of the 3D array. In order to do a orthogonal projection, i simply sum up the arrays along one axis. This is my code for doing that:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#shape of the 'image' array is (256, 256, 176) so i am assuming there are 256 slices and row and column of each slice is 256x176
image = np.load('brain_ct.npy')

#when i sum along axis 0 or axis 1, the image shows up as blank with some warnings
#(Warning: converting a masked element to nan)
#only summing up along axis 2 works (not sure why is that)
collapsed = np.sum(image, axis=2)

plt.imshow(collapsed, cmap='gray')
```

I am not sure why summing up along axis 0 and 1 does not work. Also, i am not sure what view (top/down/side) axis 2 is giving me? Finally, if summing up along one axis gives orthogonal projection, how can i go about doing an oblique and perspective projection. Is there any transformation matrix that i have to multiply the image coordinates with?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: It's likely that any slice will be a valid image in any direction. Have you considered. Displaying some images to check?

Comment: Yes, slicing it in different direction does produce an image, but summing it up along axis 0 and axis 1 does not. I am also little confused that whether summing it along axis 0 shows the top view of the 3D cube or the front view.

Comment: Why do you think summing will give you a meaningful image?

Comment: I am trying to do a perspective projection on the image so i started with a parallel projection and that is why i am summing it along one axis

Comment: I'm not sure that makes sense. What do you expect summing to accomplish with regards to projection?

Comment: If you have a masked 3d array as your error suggests, you likely want to construct a 3d solid polyhedron or mesh from it and display that. It's doable, but not trivial. You may want to research that a bit first.

Comment: I found the problem. The array had alot of "nan" values and summing up along the axis was making all the values "nan". so i changed all the nan values to 0 and now it works. Could you point me to the direction of how can i do a perspective projection with the array. Thanks!

Comment: Perspective projection depends on the data that you have.

Answer (score 1):

The error appears to show that you are loading a `numpy.ma.MaskedArray` rather than a NumPy array. However, I don't understand why you would not get the error along axis=2, since any masked points will be projected along each dimension. It could be that you have a whole plane masked, and then summing along 0 will just give you an array of nans. I am not sure but it could be that `np.sum` does not handle masked arrays properly, and you should instead use `image.sum()`, which might know better how to handle the masks. If you share your `.npy` file we can provide a more personalised response.

In general, summing is one way to project, but you could also do `max()`, which is the most common form of volumetric projection.

Regarding oblique projections, that's far more than can be succinctly summarised in a SO answer, but in general yes, you want to transform your image and then do the projection. You can look at the `scipy.ndimage` module for more information on this.

Comment: Hi Juan, Thank you for your input. I was wondering if you could share the transformation matrix for oblique and perspective projection. Different resources give a slightly different matrix so i am not sure which one to follow.

Comment: My go-to resource is the wikipedia page on homogeneous coordinates, and links found therein: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates